# DropDown and Textbox data to ms access and gridview display in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, ms-access-2010

I have a dropdown and a textbox .I hardcoded the values for dropdown ,and textbox values are entered by user on the webpage.I want to insert the data first into ms access and also populate the gridview from the ms access in the same page.

Problem is its not updating my ms access table and gridview is getting loaded on the webpage but also not getting updated.Please help i am new to C# coding.

Following is the code i am using-

`Code for dropdown-`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="113px"> 
  <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Class</asp:ListItem> 
  <asp:ListItem Value="Class 0">Class 0</asp:ListItem> 
  <asp:ListItem Value="Class 1">Class 1</asp:ListItem> 
  <asp:ListItem Value="Class 2">Class 2</asp:ListItem> 
  <asp:ListItem Value="Class 3">Class 3</asp:ListItem> 
  asp:ListItem Value="Class 4">Class 4</asp:ListItem> 
</asp:DropDownList> 

using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
OleDbConnection con;
OleDbCommand cmd;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


using (con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +    @"DATA SOURCE=C:\Users\gandhs3\Desktop\Excel.accdb"))
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into ClassLevel([Class],[18th])values(@class, @th)";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@class", OleDbType.VarChar).Value =    DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@th", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            DropDownList1.Text = "";
            TextBox2.Text = "";

        }
        BindUserDetails();
    }
    protected void BindUserDetails()
    {
    //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt;
    string strquery = "SELECT * FROM ClassLevel";
    using (con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"DATA SOURCE=C:\Users\gandhs3\Desktop\Excel.accdb"))
    {
    using (cmd = new OleDbCommand(strquery, con))
    {
        con.Open();

    OleDbDataAdapter Da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    dt = new DataTable();
    Da.Fill(dt);
    }
    }
    GridView1.DataSource=dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

}

Code for dropdown-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="113px"> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Class</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Class 0">Class 0</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Class 1">Class 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Class 2">Class 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Class 3">Class 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Class 4">Class 4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Code for dropdown-
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="16px"  Width="113px">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Class</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Class 0">Class 0</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Class 1">Class 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Class 2">Class 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Class 3">Class 3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Class 4">Class 4</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: why is this line commented out 
`//cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` how do you expect to do the insert

Comment: because code was throwing error at this line- When i run the code and select class from dropdown and enter textbox value-suppose i select class 0 and save it -   "An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Class 0'.   "

Comment: because code was throwing error at this line- When i run the code and select class from dropdown and enter textbox value-suppose i select class 0 and save it - "An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Class 0'. "

Comment: are you stepping through the code @Sandy ? also why are you doing this in the Button Click event
`DropDownList1.Text = "";
TextBox2.Text = "";` you already have the items hard coded so why are you trying to clear them.. I think you need to understand what's going on when postbacks are happening in regard to the dropdownlist

Comment: I am able to solve the above using with the followin code-'cmd.CommandText = "insert into ClassLevel([Class],[18th])values(@class, @th)";

   cmd.Parameters.Add("@class", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@th", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;'

Comment: Now i am facing one more problem-My gridview is not populating from the first row and therefore data in ms access database. Also i want to avoid duplicate entries if class 0 already entered then corresponding "18th" column value should be edited and not a new row should be added.How will i achieve that?

Comment: if you are going to post code @Sandy please edit your original question and put it there also if the datagrid does not populating you need to read up on the following `C# how to bind data to a datagridview as well as read up on some basic sql` if you do not want duplicates then either looking to changing the select query to use the `Distinct keyword or ad a where clause`